# Sql subquery comparing two counts

Tags: sql, count, subquery

I have the following query that returns all the people of the register that have the type 'C' and the number of rows for each person with the type 'C'. Each person can have type 'C' or type 'V'

```
select count(type), number_document 
from register 
where type = 'C' 
group by number_document ;
```

I want to return ONLY the people that all his rows have the type 'C', so I need to do a subquery comparing the total number of rows with the count(type).

I don't know how to introduce a subquery here.

Comment: Please tag your DBMS (version included)

Answer (score 0):

You could use NOT EXISTS to exclude users that also have type 'V':

```
select count(type), number_document 
from register ro 
where type = 'C' 
    AND NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT TOP 1 NULL 
    FROM register ri 
    WHERE ri.User = ro.User 
        AND ri.type='V')
group by number_document;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
select count(r.type), r.number_document 
from register r
where r.type = 'C' AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM register r2
    WHERE r.number_document = r2.number_document AND r2.type <> 'C'
)
group by r.number_document ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query has two condition

1. filter registers that all 'type' values are same
2. then filter persons who are in 'C' type

   ```
   select count(r.type), r.number_document 
   from register r
   where r.type = ALL (
       SELECT r2.type
       FROM register r2
       WHERE r.number_document = r2.number_document
   )
   AND r.type = 'C'
   group by r.number_document ;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

How about this? The HAVING clause checks whether the only TYPE column value is 'C' (because MIN = MAX = C).

```
select number_document, count(*)
from register
group by number_document
having min(type) = max(type) and min(type) = 'C';
```